# Google sheets filter custom formula is moved by one row

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-filter-view

I created a column of total profit in google sheets and my goal is to filter values which are less then 70% of previous profit value ([screenshot so you can understand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/97l75.png)).

But when I apply this condition to the filter custom formula ([here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ijmRx.png)) is not filtering the values which are less then 70% but the values before them, instead it is moved by one row ([hopefully you will understand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1NGN.png)).

It may be it is something easy to fix but i really couldn't find out. Thanks for your future advice and time!

*EDIT: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JcHVrpOCLEdMiTF3YD0qvJiHPsi6J2QwFPN-XOfAipY/edit?usp=sharing sheet in view mode

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JcHVrpOCLEdMiTF3YD0qvJiHPsi6J2QwFPN-XOfAipY/edit?usp=sharing if you need editor permissions, i can do that too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to shift it:

```
=$B2/$B1>0.7
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, this works fine (only the first value is removed, but i dont need it). But why this works? Why do i have to put it in the next column? If you have a moment, can you explain please?

Comment: you can put it in B1 too if you want. it doesn't matter coz range is locked with `$`

Comment: when i put the filter in B1 everything is gone but its ok, it works ;) thank you again very much <3